# How to add Space between sidebar and footer widget in Wordpress theme

Tags: theme-development, themes

How to add Space between sidebar and footer widget in word press theme.In bottom of our [Site](http://www.urdustatus.com), I added footer and how can i increase space between sidebar and footer.Its very close and touching the each other. You can see in bottom of home page.

Comment: This is a question about css, not about WP

Answer (score 0):

Add to the style.css file of your theme:

```
.footer {padding-top:15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding` property to `footer` class in `style.css` file.

For example (and I recommend):

```
.footer{
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

This code add 20 pixels padding to top and bottom of footer section.

Answer (score 0):

Using [padding](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/padding/) to increase the whitespace around your `.footer`.

> padding: {top / right / bottom / left};
>
> padding: {top} {right} {bottom} {left};
>
> padding: {top / bottom} {left / right};

Use 2 values to only increase the top and bottom space uniformly.

```
.footer {
    padding: 30px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joel.Issue is resolved.I am successfully able to add space.

Comment: Great, then you can mark this question answered